# remove comma in data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a web api with a function:

```
function fodboldStream() {
  //$timezone = date_default_timezone_get('Europe/Copenhagen');
  //$date = date('Y-m-d');

    $result = query("SELECT kampe2.dato,kampe2.id,kampe2.sqltime, kampe2.tidspunkt,kampe2.hiddenmatch,  turneringer.turnering, turneringer.image, holdH.hold AS hjemmehold, holdU.hold AS udehold, holdH.imagebig AS hjemmeimage, holdU.imagebig AS udeimage, tvkanal.kanal,tvkanal.imageny, kampe2.optakt, kampe2.info, kampe2.type 
                     FROM kampe2 
                     INNER JOIN turneringer ON kampe2.turnering=turneringer.id
                     INNER JOIN tvkanal ON kampe2.kanal1=tvkanal.id 
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN hold holdH ON holdH.id = kampe2.hjemmehold
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN hold holdU ON holdU.id = kampe2.udehold
                     WHERE kampe2.hiddenmatch=0  AND kampe2.dato >= cast((now()) as date) ORDER BY kampe2.tidspunkt ");

  if (!$result['error']) {
    print json_encode  ($result);
  } else {
    errorJson('fodbold stream is broken');
  }

}
```

This gives me an array like this:

```
result = (
    {
        dato = "2015-03-01";
        hiddenmatch = 0;
        hjemmehold = "Val\U00e8ncia CF";
        hjemmeimage = "1775.png";
        id = 7571;
        image = "5_ll.png";
        imageny = "Canal9.png";
        info = "";
        kanal = "Canal 9";
        optakt = "11:55";
        sqltime = 1425207600;
        tidspunkt = "12:00";
        turnering = "Liga BBVA";
        type = "";
        udehold = "Real Sociedad";
        udeimage = "1742.png";
    }
```

My problem is that `tvkanal.kanal` only gives me `1`, the row in the table is `11`, `61`, `45`.

How do I, in this 1 query get them as `tvkanal1 =  x tvkanal2 = x` and `tvkanal3` there can be from `1 to 3 "tvkanal"`?

If I use find in set:

```
$result = query("SELECT kampe2.dato,kampe2.id,kampe2.sqltime, kampe2.tidspunkt,kampe2.hiddenmatch,  turneringer.turnering, turneringer.image, holdH.hold AS hjemmehold, holdU.hold AS udehold, holdH.imagebig AS hjemmeimage, holdU.imagebig AS udeimage, kampe2.optakt, kampe2.info,GROUP_CONCAT(tvkanal.image) as TVimg, kampe2.type 
                     FROM kampe2 
                     INNER JOIN turneringer ON kampe2.turnering=turneringer.id
                     INNER JOIN tvkanal ON FIND_IN_SET(tvkanal.id, kampe2.kanal1)>0
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN hold holdH ON holdH.id = kampe2.hjemmehold
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN hold holdU ON holdU.id = kampe2.udehold
                     WHERE kampe2.hiddenmatch=0  AND kampe2.dato >= cast((now()) as date) ORDER BY kampe2.tidspunkt ");
```

I get :

```
result = (
    {
      TVimg = "ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,TV3-Sport-1-v2.png,TV3-Sport-1-v2.png,3Plus-Logo-v2.png,canal9-v3.png,TV3-Sport-1-v2.png,canal8-v3.png,TV3-Sport-1-v2.png,3Plus-Logo-v2.png,TV3-Sport-1-v2.png,TV3-Sport-1-v2.png,TV3-Sport-1-v2.png,canal9-v3.png,canal8-v3.png,canal9-v3.png,TV3-Sport-1-v2.png,3Plus-Logo-v2.png,TV3-Sport-1-v2.png,canal8-v3.png,TV3-Sport-1-v2.png,TV3-Sport-1-v2.png,3Plus-Logo-v2.png,canal9-v3.png,TV3-Sport-1-v2.png,canal8-v3.png,TV3-Sport-1-v2.png,TV3-Sport-1-v2.png,TV3-Sport-1-v2.png,3Plus-Logo-v2.png,canal8-v3.png,TV3-Sport-1-v2.png,canal9-v3.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke-fastlagt.png,ikke";
      dato = "2015-06-07";
      hiddenmatch = 0;
      hjemmehold = "FC Vestsj\U00e6lland";
      hjemmeimage = "555.png";
      id = 6180;
      image = "Alka-superliga2.png";
      info = "";
      optakt = "";
      sqltime = 1433685600;
      tidspunkt = "16:00";
      turnering = "Alka Superligaen";
      type = "";
      udehold = "Silkeborg IF";
      udeimage = "551.png";
    }
);
}
```

I'm doing some work.

Comment: Look for FIND_IN_SET but the real answer is dont store comma delimited values in a table

Comment: edited with find in set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made a new function :

```
function fodboldTVKanalerStream($kampId) {



    $result = query("SELECT kampe2.dato, GROUP_CONCAT(tvkanal.imageny) as TVimg
                                  FROM kampe2 
                                  INNER JOIN tvkanal ON FIND_IN_SET(tvkanal.id, kampe2.kanal1)>0
                                  WHERE kampe2.hiddenmatch=0 AND kampe2.id='%d' AND kampe2.dato >= cast((now()) as date) ORDER BY kampe2.tidspunkt",$kampId);

if (!$result['error']) {
    print json_encode($result);
} else {
    errorJson('TvImage stream is broken');
}

}
```

and the i do the split in  object c like this:

```
 NSString *thisGameId = [game objectForKey:@"id"];
    //...........tv image handling ...............................
    [API sharedInstance].imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"images/TVkanaler/new/"];
    [[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"fodboldTVKanalerStream", @"command",thisGameId,@"kampId", nil] onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {

        NSArray *daTa = [json objectForKey:@"result"];


        NSArray *tvimages = [daTa mutableArrayValueForKey:@"TVimg"];

        NSString *joinedComponents = [tvimages componentsJoinedByString:@","];

        NSArray* myArray = [joinedComponents  componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

        if (myArray.count <2) {
            NSString* firstString = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];

            // .......... making the sever call .........................
            API* api = [API sharedInstance];
            NSURL* imageURL = [api urlForImageWithId:firstString  isThumb:NO];
            AFImageRequestOperation* imageOperation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageURL] success:^(UIImage *image) {

                //create an image view, add it to the view

                cell.chanelImageView.image = image;
                cell.chanel2ImageView.image = Nil;
                cell.paddingImageView2.hidden = YES;

            }];

            NSOperationQueue* queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
            [queue addOperation:imageOperation];


            //NSLog(@"1 billede %@",firstString);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use multiple INNER JOINS:

```
INNER JOIN tvkanal AS tvkanal1 ON kampe2.kanal1=tvkanal.id 
INNER JOIN tvkanal AS tvkanal2 ON kampe2.kanal2=tvkanal.id 
INNER JOIN tvkanal AS tvkanal3 ON kampe2.kanal3=tvkanal.id
```

Then in your SELECT fields:

```
tvkanal1.kanal,tvkanal1.imageny,tvkanal2.kanal,tvkanal2.imageny,tvkanal3.kanal,tvkanal3.imageny
```

Comment: the problem is that kampe2.kanal1 is  comma separated  like  3,10,2